# Python functional programming list comprehension with function composition and while loop

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm tinkering with reinforcement learning, trying to implement simple environment using functional programming.

I have functions `step: State, Action -> State` and `action_space: State -> [Action, ...]`.

I'm looking for functional programming way of implementing iterative composition of function `step` over initial `State`

```
s = State()
e = [s]
while action_space(s):
    a = best(action_space(s))
    s = step(s, a)
    e.append(s)
```

So what I think I need is way of creating comprehension `[f(x) and c(x), f(f(x)) and c(f(x)), f(f(f(x))) and c(f(f(x)), ...]`, but without unnecessary evaluations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your question is? Given this confusing spec write teh codez for me?  In any case I believe what you want is use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) which is Python's fold operation.

Comment: @Bakuriu actually, this is an [unfold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism).

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm asking for directions or at least some keywords to look for. I think solution I'm looking for is exactly oposite of `reduce`. While `reduce` is taking 2 elements and returning one, function I need would take 1 (last) element and return 2 - the one it takes and one after applying function. I guess `expand` could be name for it.

Answer (score 1):

Comprehension is not possible for this scenario, but you could create a generator. Before going into that, I would also suggest that you define your *best* and *step* functions in such a way that they return something falsy (like `False` or `None`) whenever the last (*actions*) argument is falsy. It will simplify your code.

Then you can define this generator:

```
def unfold(s):
    while s:
        yield s
        s = step(s, best(action_space(s)))
```

This has the advantage of being lazy.  You can use it like this:

```
e = [s for s in unfold(State())]
```

Or just:

```
e = list(unfold(State()))
```

A more functional programming approach could be this recursive function:

```
def unfold(s):
    return [s] + unfold(step(s, best(action_space(s)))) if s else []

e = unfold(State())
```

If you find the need of a named function annoying, then you could go for this trick:

```
e = (lambda unfold:lambda s:unfold(unfold,s))(
        lambda unfold, s: [s] + unfold(unfold, step(s, best(action_space(s)))) if s else []
    )(State())
```

This is quite obscure though. The first function is called immediately with a another function as argument (the one on the second line): the actual *unfold* function, which gets is name by the parameter name of the first function.

Then this first function returns another function (`lambda s:unfold(unfold,s)`) that accepts the *state* argument, and calls *unfold* with it. We also invoke that function immediately, passing it the initial value `State()`.

Note that *unfold* is also passed itself down the recursion tree so to keep it within scope.

Comment: I guess it is close. It gives the right outcome, but it is not pure functional programming.

Comment: Added some alternatives which are more *functional programming*.